# Is it possible for two neutron star to merge into a larger neutron star?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, neutron-stars

Is it possible for two low mass neutron star to merge into a larger neutron star, or will this always result in a black hole?

What would this event likely look like?

Comment: If the total mass of two neutron stars is below [TOV Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit), I think it might be possible.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star_merger): “When the two neutron stars meet, their merger leads to the formation of either a more massive neutron star, or a black hole (depending on whether the mass of the remnant exceeds the Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff limit).”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems possible, but unlikely. The lowest mass neutron star known is a bit over a solar mass, and the highest is a bit over two solar masses. Lower masses are thought to be possible in theory, but they may not form in reality. Higher masses are thought to be unstable. Also, some mass is ejected in a merger, and some is lost to gravitational radiation.

So, a binary made of two minimum-mass neutron stars could probably produce a neutron star in a merger.